# The best way of loading and parsing css stylesheet in flash as3

Tags: css, actionscript-3, stylesheet, textfield

Is not the first time that I have this "problem". Other times, I did solve it avoiding the problem, but now I want to face it.

The idea is to load some file "myBeautifulStyles.css" with a simple css code like this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

h1, h2, h3, p, a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

h2 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

h3 {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}


p {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

If I just loaded it as a text and try a StyleSheet.parseCSS() the result is null, the .styleNames returns an empty Array. I'm wondering if is about the text (break-line marks, initial codes...) or something else is missing. The examples around the web are always single line code. It's easy to clean this text and put it in a single line, but will work?

And most important, what's the best approach of this task?

Edit: as required, this code loads de css file trough a php (for avoiding caches):

```
var ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest(httpBase+"admin_arqs.php");
ur.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var Vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
Vars.op = "ler";
Vars.url = httpBase+"conteudos_estilos.css";
ur.data = Vars;
var ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ul.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
ul.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, estilos);
ul.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioerror);
ul.load(ur);

function estilos(e){
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    e.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioerror);
    var Res = JSON.decode(clearRes(String(e.target.data)));
    if(Res.erro!="OK"){
        msg("Erro: "+Res.msg);
    } else {
        ini_edit(Res.dados);
    }
}

function ioerror(e){
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, estilos);
    msg("Erro de IO!");
}
```

This part set the stylesheet:

```
trace("Estilos em string: "+css);
var estilos:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
estilos.parseCSS(css);
texto.styleSheet = estilos;
trace("Estilos definidos: "+estilos.styleNames);
```

The first trace generate the css text is displayed above. The second should display an Array with names. I also try tracing estilos.styleName.length and is zero.

texto is the TextField and css came from the Res.dados.

Comment: show us your code please , especially part with loading

Comment: I'd put the code above. I did the test: processing the css to all in one line and deleting the other elements (including comments), IT WORKS! So far is my solution, if nothing better exists. However, the html rendering is different from a browser: there is no spacing between p tags and line-breaks are accepted. More processing, or there is some adjust I'm missing in TextField?

Comment: I have tried it , see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this line `@charset "UTF-8";` at the head of css file causes the problem. Try to remove it and see if it solving the issue.

Comment: Only removing this line solve the problem, or put it all in one line is required too?

Comment: @GustavoPinent just remove this line. we want to keep our `css` natural ! they are not one-lined in nature , right? ;)

Comment: @GustavoPinent glad it works ! i must say that it was interesting issue